# Java source files - Is encoding still relevant once compiled?

Tags: java, javac

I do know that loading a file in Java without specifying the encoding to use is *platform dependant*. But my question is about *the text contained in the .java source files themselves* : Is the encoding used for those files still relevant **once compiled**?

For example, if I have a `test.java` file on Windows which is `Cp1252` encoded and contains :

```
private String encodingTest = "Bœuf fûmé";
```

If I compile it using `-encoding Cp1252`, what happens exactly to this text in the resulting `.class`? Does the encoding still matter? Or is the encoding standardized by Java when compiling?

Will the resulting `.class` be platform dependant? Can I have a different result if I output this text on Windows, Linux, Solaris? Can an encoding configuration on the server impact the rendering of this text in a way or another?

Comment: I think if the resulting `.class` were platform dependent, it would break one of the main ideas of Java -- write once, run anywhere. I *believe* that `char` values in Java are encoded in Unicode, but as I don't have a source, I won't post that as an answer. My guess as to what `-encoding` does is tells the compiler what encoding the source file is in, so you might end up with something different in the bytecode, but the bytecode *should* be have a canonical representation for a given character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code encoding is *very* relevant *while* compiling, as the OP says in his post. However after compiling, all literal text is stored as (modified-) UTF-8 encoded strings.

All string literals, class/method/field names and references to them are stored in the constant pool of the `.class` file in **UTF-8** encoding:

[From the JVM spec (for Java version 1.7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7):

> 4.4.7. The CONSTANT_Utf8_info Structure
>
> The CONSTANT_Utf8_info structure is used to represent constant string
>   values:
>
> [...]
>
> String content is encoded in modified UTF-8. Modified UTF-8
>   strings are encoded so that code point sequences that contain only
>   non-null ASCII characters can be represented using only 1 byte per
>   code point, but all code points in the Unicode codespace can be
>   represented.

So once your source code is compiled, it is stored in a known character encoding (UTF-8) and you no longer need to specify the source file encoding.

In general, section [4.4 of the JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4) explains how the constant pool works and that Strings, class/field/method names etc. are represented by a `CONSTANT_Utf8_info` structure.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, java always use UTF-16 in String objects, so it is "unaware" of the encoding ever used in the source code.

Just to confirm by yourself, have a look at the source code for the [String class](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html), there is not information about encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Java intentionally makes a distinction between binary data (byte, Input/OutputStream) and text (String, Reader/Writer) which is in Unicode, so one may use and combine any script. The .class files thus contain the text constants as UTF-8, and internally in memory the String and char is in UTF-16.

In this way java actually is one of the clearest encoding aware languages, where it not for the fact, that a java source may be in any encoding, defaulting to the platform encoding, and the compilation needs to be given the same encoding (or defaulting to the same one).

Nowadays one sees projects where encoding for source and compiler is specified as UTF-8.